# How to bind component method to button's 'onclick' outside Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngzone

I have an Angular 4 app and a component, which generate some markup dynamically. And I need to bind this component's method to some element in this markup.
The only way, that I found is to generate this element with `onclick` attribute. And so now my component's constructor looks like that:

```
constructor(private _zone: NgZone) { 
    window['Component'] = {
      myMethod: this.myMethod.bind(this),
      zone: _zone
    }
}
```

...and the peice of my generated markup looks like that:

```
<button onclick="window.Component.myMethod()">I was generated dynamically after Angular compilation, so you can't use '(click)="method(params)"' on me! Haha!</button>
```

And it works! Almost... After clickin the button I need some event on `window` to be fired (e.g. focus or blur), only then my method runs. Please, anybody, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use : `this.zone.runOutsideAngular`

i have attach sample to illustrate where you have button out of angular and event Binding inside component. As illustrate on my sample, don't forget to unbind your event onDestroy.

```
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.foo();
  });      
});
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtkw3z?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

---

update 1:

I have create custom directive dedicated to bind click event on your button.

I have remove DOMSanitizer because we add Event.stopPropagation() automatically. So you have to do your own control if string is safe or not.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[profil]'
})
export class UserProfilDirective implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    @Input('profil') html: string;

    constructor(
        private el: ElementRef,
        private zone: NgZone,
        private renderer: Renderer2
    ) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        //Take your html and add it as child html if current directive instance.
        this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.html;
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        //Out of angular.
        this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            // For each .profil of current instance.
            [].forEach.call(this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.profil'), (el:Element, index: number) => {
                //Ask rendering to add onClick event.
                this.renderer.listen(el, 'click', (e) => {
                  //Do what ever you want with data profil such as output Event
                  console.log(e.srcElement.getAttribute('data-profile'));
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Source code here :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cua3is?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: thanx for ur answer. I'd use this solution, but the thing is that my dynamically generated markup changes quite often and has a lot of such buttons.

Comment: here it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bnr4hu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Oups, i am sorry, i have forget to fork before editing. link is : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cua3is?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: ur example looks cool. I'l try to integrate ur solution and let u know if it works. Thanx!

Comment: Ok;, please mark answer to valid if this solve your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was that when I run the method outside the Angular zone, UI douesn't refresh. So i did this:

```
(<any>window).myMethod = (params) => this._zone.run(
    () => {
        this.myMethod(params);
    });
```

Don't know how good this solution is, but it works fine.

**UPD:** Oops, not fine. The method doesn't run the first time I click the button, after that everything's ok.